# Want to make switch root for STP, command not available

Tags: cisco, switch, stp

I want to make a certain switch in the network root, but all I remember is the command "set spantree root vlan-id"

Sadly, the "set" command is not available on this switch. How do I proceed?

EDIT: I think I did it with the following command, in config mode:

```
spanning-tree vlan <number> root primary
```

Sadly, I have no idea how to confirm this. That becomes the question now.

Comment: Are you in enable mode? Is this a CatOS switch or IOS switch?

Comment: I am in enable mode, and it's an IOS switch: C2960 version 12.2(25)FX

Comment: Editted the first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1(Enter global configuration mode): configure terminal

2(change priority): spanning-tree vlan  priority primary

if you have problem try

(number priority): (config)#spanning-tree vlan vlan-id priority 24576

(disable uplinkfast, UplinkFast cannot be enabled on VLANs that have been configured with a switch priority): (config)#no spanning-tree uplinkfast